# How to access response.body from a JavaScript function called in Objective-C?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm using Parse Cloud Code to handle some server-side logic for my iOS app.

I query for Parse chatRooms objects. If the desired object exists, I have no problem accessing it, but if I have to create it with an external JavaScript function (to get around user permission issues), I am having trouble accessing the object that is returned by said JS function.

**iOS ViewController**.

```
-(void)chatRoomQuery
{
   ....

    [combinedChatRoomQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (![objects count] == 0) {
            [self.chatButton setTitle:@"continue chat with this user" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.selectedChat = objects[0];
        }
        else if ([objects count] == 0){
            [self.chatButton setTitle:@"create new chat with this user" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"addUsersToChatRoom" withParameters:@{@"user1" : [PFUser currentUser].objectId, @"user2" : self.giveItem.itemGiver.objectId} block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                self.selectedChat = response.body.currentChat;
            }];
        };
    }];

}
```

The "else if" block calls this **JavaScript function** saved to my Parse Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addUsersToChatRoom", function(request, response){

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 

  var user1id = request.params.user1;
  var user2id = request.params.user2;

  var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
  var user1 = new User({ objectId: user1id });
  var user2 = new User({ objectId: user2id });

  var ChatRoom = Parse.Object.extend("ChatRoom");
  var currentChat = new ChatRoom();

  currentChat.set("user1", user1);
  currentChat.set("user2", user2);

  currentChat.save(null, {
    success: function(currentChat){
        console.log("YEAAA the chat room is saved");
        response.body = currentChat;
    },
    error: function(currentChat, error){
        console.log("FAILED to save chatroom" + error.message);
    }
  });

});
```

As you can see in my iOS code sample, under the else if block, I set

```
self.selectedChat = response.body.currentChat;
```

But I get the **error**

```
Use of undeclared identifier "response"
```

How do I access the response.body of my JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cloud code should return the success method instead of setting the body property:

```
response.success(currentChat);
```

Your iOS code should be accessing the returned object, not the body of the response which doesn't exist:

```
self.selectedChat = object;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick right answer. Would you mind answering why this is the case?

Comment: That's just the way it works.  response.success() or response.error() to respond to a cloud function, and 'object' is what is defined in the continuation block of your cloud function.